How to click all plus symbol present in website using selenium python?
In the following link, how to click  all plus symbol in the selenium python?
https://www.screener.in/company/HAL/

I would like to click all + button given in the below screenshot ?

Tried multiple way but I can not move beyond driver.get
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.screener.in/company/ADANIENT/consolidated/')



The website has some sort of safeguards against web crawlers, so you'll have to maximize the browser window (if it isn't already) so you don't get the error telling you some other element <x> will receive the click.
Adding to that, my XPATH query still picks up some hidden  buttons that just show up in inspector but not visible on the web page, and subsequently get caught by Selenium as "not interactable").
In total there are 23 of these buttons, the following code captures all visible 19:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException  # To catch our culprit(s)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()  # To make sure elements are accessible
driver.get('https://www.screener.in/company/ADANIENT/consolidated/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//span[@class='blue-icon']"))
)

# Selenium < v4.3
# blue_icons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='blue-icon']/ancestor::button")

# Selenium >= v4.3
blue_icons = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//span[@class='blue-icon']/ancestor::button")

clicked = 0
for icon in blue_icons:
    try:
        # time.sleep(0.1) # Optional
        icon.click()
        clicked += 1
    except ElementNotInteractableException as e:
        print(e)

print(f"{clicked} `+` buttons clicked.\n{len(blue_icons)-clicked} not interactable.")


@M. A. it is throwing same error I was getting earlier but any way thank you for effort & have my upvote. Error code: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (143, 9). Other element would receive the click: 
